# Flutter application can't running after add firebase_messaging package

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is the log from vscode

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              3.9s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           10.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:195:43: error: expected a type
    - (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                                              ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:302:53: error: nullability specifier 'nonnull' conflicts with
    existing specifier 'nullable'
        didReceiveRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken {
                                                        ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:307:24: error: expected a type
        didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                           ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:141:30: error: property 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' not
    found on object of type 'FIRMessaging *'
        [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
                                 ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:160:21: warning: 'FIRInstanceID' is deprecated: FIRInstanceID
    is deprecated, please use FIRInstallations for installation identifier handling and use FIRMessaging for FCM registration token handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID]
                        ^
    In module 'FirebaseInstanceID' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:74:
    /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Firebase/InstanceID/Public/FIRInstanceID.h:190:1: note: 'FIRInstanceID' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    __deprecated_msg("FIRInstanceID is deprecated, please use FIRInstallations for installation "
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation
    .h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFo
    undation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro
    '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:161:33: warning: 'FIRInstanceIDResult' is deprecated:
    FIRInstanceIDResult is deprecated, please use FIRInstallations for app instance identifier handling and use FIRMessaging for FCM registration token handling.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            instanceIDWithHandler:^(FIRInstanceIDResult *_Nullable instanceIDResult,
                                    ^
    In module 'FirebaseInstanceID' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:74:
    /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Firebase/InstanceID/Public/FIRInstanceID.h:153:1: note: 'FIRInstanceIDResult' has been explicitly marked
    deprecated here
    __deprecated_msg("FIRInstanceIDResult is deprecated, please use FIRInstallations "
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation
    .h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFo
    undation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro
    '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:161:9: warning: 'instanceIDWithHandler:' is deprecated: Use
    `Installations.installationID(completion:)` to get the app instance identifier instead. Use `Messaging.token(completion:)` to get FCM registration token instead.
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            instanceIDWithHandler:^(FIRInstanceIDResult *_Nullable instanceIDResult,
            ^
    In module 'FirebaseInstanceID' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:74:
    /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Firebase/InstanceID/Public/FIRInstanceID.h:215:5: note: 'instanceIDWithHandler:' has been explicitly marked
    deprecated here
        __deprecated_msg("Use `Installations.installationID(completion:)` to get the app instance "
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation
    .h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFo
    undation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro
    '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:171:21: warning: 'FIRInstanceID' is deprecated: FIRInstanceID
    is deprecated, please use FIRInstallations for installation identifier handling and use FIRMessaging for FCM registration token handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] deleteIDWithHandler:^void(NSError *_Nullable error) {
                        ^
    In module 'FirebaseInstanceID' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:74:
    /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Firebase/InstanceID/Public/FIRInstanceID.h:190:1: note: 'FIRInstanceID' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    __deprecated_msg("FIRInstanceID is deprecated, please use FIRInstallations for installation "
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation
    .h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFo
    undation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro
    '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:171:33: warning: 'deleteIDWithHandler:' is deprecated: Use
    `Installations.delete(completion:)` instead. Also check `Messaging.deleteData(completion:)`if you want to delete FCM registration token. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] deleteIDWithHandler:^void(NSError *_Nullable error) {
                                    ^
    In module 'FirebaseInstanceID' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:74:
    /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Firebase/InstanceID/Public/FIRInstanceID.h:321:33: note: 'deleteIDWithHandler:' has been explicitly marked
    deprecated here
                                    __deprecated_msg("Use `Installations.delete(completion:)` instead. "
                                    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/abdurrohman/bsi/flutter_firebase/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation
    .h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFo
    undation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro
    '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:196:52: error: property 'appData' not found on object of type
    '__strong id'
      [self didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                       ^
    /Users/abdurrohman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:308:63: error: property 'appData' not found on object of type
    '__strong id'
      [_channel invokeMethod:@"onMessage" arguments:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                                  ^
    5 warnings and 6 errors generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target
    'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target
    'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Comment: I think you need to change the `deployment target` to `11` in your Xcode

Comment: Hmm it's not worked, any other options? @ShubhamNarkhede

Comment: Try this. Open your project in xcode. In your folder structure go to the folder Flutter, there is a file named AppFrameworkInfo.plist open it and change the MinimumOsVersion to String 9.0 o 9.3. Try to match the Ios Deployment Target of your Runner file.  https://imgur.com/a/SQ0Sgep

Comment: Setup on ios working as well, but i got difference error from gradle when running on Android. Here is the log ```* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:generateDebugRFile'.          
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_core:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-common:.               
     Required by:                                                       
         project :firebase_core    ``` cc @L.Chi

Comment: Solve, thanks to @ShubhamNarkhede. I don't know what wrong whit my setup, i just hope FlutterFire documentation get some new update.

Comment: One again to @L.Chi.

Comment: Adding firebase_core to the pubspec.yaml fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#SOLVED

References:

1. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview
2. https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/1004

I got some error on iOS setup and this is my solved setup on Podfile.

```rb
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

$FirebaseSDKVersion = '8.3.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

When i check on Android, i got some new error again. Some problem come from Firebase initialization on Activity and Application. This is my solved setup on Android.

**MainApplication.kt**

```kotlin
package id.refactory.flutter_firebase

import android.content.Context
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex
import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService;

class MainApplication : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"))
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
package id.refactory.flutter_firebase

import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }
}
```

Hope you all guys solve your problem that related with this question.

Comment: thx, ios works fine with overriding firebase core

Comment: Edited for flutter_local_notification packages

Comment: Where did you find this? Can you please share the source link ?

Comment: Thank you so so much. I was stuck on this for the last 2 days. @AbdurRohman Please accept this answer.

Comment: @nimi0112 u can check on references section, thanks

Comment: @AbdurRohman I got another error :  error: nullability specifier 'nullable' conflicts with existing specifier 'nonnull'
        didReceiveRegistrationToken:(nullable NSString *)fcmToken {
                                                         ^